# React-Materialize - How to disable CollapsibleItem behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, materialize

I've been playing around with React-Materialize to help me learn React, but I've come across a problem with the CollapsibleItem component, if I have a child with an onClick handler on that CollapsibleItem.

```
const HomeworkDetails = ({props}) => {

return (
    <Collapsible className="homework-list">
    {
        props.homeworks.map(hwork => {
            console.log(hwork.dateDue);
            return hwork.student === props.student ? (
            <CollapsibleItem className="card-content light-green purple-text text-darken-4" key={hwork._id} 
            header={<div><Col s={3}>{hwork.subject}</Col>
                         <Col s={3}>{hwork.dateSet.split("T")[0]}</Col>
                         <Col s={3}>{hwork.dateDue.split("T")[0]}</Col>
                         <Col s={3} onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); alert('Hi');}}>{hwork.status}</Col>
                    </div>}>
                <h6 className="homework-list-h6">Details:</h6>
                {hwork.details}
            </CollapsibleItem>
            ) : null
        })
    }
    </Collapsible>
);
```

}

The intention is that when the user clicks on the 4th Column that is on the CollapsibleItem (this is where the homework status will be), I want to drop down a list of allowable statuses, so that the user can change it. I've currently stubbed this with a simple alert (the dropdown will be a new Component), but once the alert is dismissed after the onClick handler is executed, the CollapsibleItem then expands/collapses depending on its current state.

I would like to inhibit this expansion/collapse when the user clicks on this one child, but cannot find a way of stopping it - the e.preventDefault() doesn't do anything (and I half anticipated it wouldn't).

Any ideas?
Jools.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the click event from propagating instead of preventing the default? `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: I hadn't Tholle - but I just did - unfortunately this doesn't do anything different, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did something like this is to not initialize the collapsible at all and manually control when the `collapsible-body` is displayed. This was with regular Materalize CSS but I imagine it works similar in React-Materialize.

For example here how you would control a collapsible using a switch (with Vanilla JS):

```
const addEmailCCSwitch = document.getElementById("add-email-cc-switch")
addEmailCCSwitch.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const isChecked = addEmailCCSwitch.querySelector('input').checked;
  if (isChecked) {
    document.querySelector('.collapsible-body').style.display = "block"
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.collapsible-body').style.display = "none"
  }
});
```

Here is a codepen with the functional example: https://codepen.io/dsudomoin/pen/zYBeYyW